# android how to build a repeat AlarmManager for the day that user select every week?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to build an Activity that user could select the days they want

such as Sun, Mon, Tue, wed,...,Sat

and a method in the Activity is use to set the time user choose

```
if(action) { //10分鐘該一次
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MedicationAddRemineActivity.this ,
            0 , intent, 0 );
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP 
                    , fireTime, 10*60*1000, sender);
} else { //關閉鬧鐘
    PendingIntent cancelSecder = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MedicationAddRemineActivity.this ,
            0 , intent, 0);
    alarm.cancel(cancelSecder);
}
```

But I want to build a function to handle user selected days every week by the `radioButton`.

If the user selected Monday and Friday, device should show a dialog to user

every Monday and Friday, until it be canceled.

How do I build the function?

Count the `AlarmManager` start time:

```
long totalTime = 0;
if(moon.equals("下午")) {
    totalTime = total + 12*3600;
} else {totalTime = total + 0;}

//取得系統當時時間
Time t = new Time();
int sysHour = t.hour;
int sysMin = t.minute;
int sysSecond = t.second;
long sysTotal = sysHour*3600 + sysMin*60 +sysSecond;

//處理用藥提醒時間
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
long transfer = Long.parseLong(format.format(totalTime));
String transferdTime = String.valueOf(sysTotal - transfer);
return transferdTime;
```